Is there a way to create a time stamp that records time a value in a drop down is selected?
I want a code in app script for google sheets, that records a (start time) time stamp when a value named " Awaiting Client Documents" is selected in the dropdown menu and then when it is no longer the selected value, to record the (end time) time stamp. But get this, the drop down is in a sheet called "Work Sheet" in column K3 and the time stamps have to be recorded on a sheet called "Data" in Column P3 (start time) and the (end time) in Q3.
PS. I have zero coding experience but I know this is a feature I need so I will be very appreciative if someone can help with this.
I tried to use chatgpt but it does not work.

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

I have zero coding experience but I know this is a feature FYI - the feature = a script can be triggered when someone edits the dropdown; the trigger is called onEdit doc ref. A second aspect of the feature is so-called Event Objects doc ref; these are information about the edited cell. The documentation describes the triggers and Event Objects and some example scripts - worth a look.

You want to create a "start" and "end" timestamps based on the value selected in a dropdown cell.
Consider this answer:

the script is executed by the onEdit trigger when any cell is edited
Event Objects are used to return information about the edited cell - including the Sheet, Column, Row and Value
the Event Objects are used to test if the edit was:

on the correct sheet
in the correct column
on the correct row
the correct value


Data validation values are:

"Awaiting Client Documents" - for "start" date
"Documents received" - for "end" date
"Neither" - for testing




function onEdit(e) {

  // list all Event Objects
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  // get the relevant Event Objects
  var editedsheet = e.range.getSheet().getName()
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  var editedValue = e.value
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited sheet = "+editedsheet+", edited row = "+editedRow+", edited Columns = "+editedCol+", edited value = "+editedValue)

  // details of the dropdown
  var sheet2Watch = "Work Sheet"
  var value2Watch1 = "Awaiting Client Documents"
  var value2Watch2 = "Documents received"
  var col2Watch = 11 // Column P
  var row2Watch = 3

  // test for the correct sheet, column, row and value
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: sheet2watch:"+sheet2Watch+", edited sheet:"+editedsheet+", edited Col:"+editedCol+", col2watch"+col2Watch+", edited row:"+editedRow+"row2watch:"+row2Watch+", edited value:"+editedValue+", value1:"+value2Watch1+", value2:"+value2Watch2)
  if ((sheet2Watch !== editedsheet || editedCol !== col2Watch || editedRow !== row2Watch) || (editedValue != value2Watch1 && editedValue != value2Watch2)){ // Work Sheet p3 = "Awaiting Client Documents" or "Documents received"
    // sheet/column/row/value don't match - do nothing
    Logger.log("DEBUG: sheet and cell and value is not a match")
    return
  }
  else{
    Logger.log("DEBUG: sheet and cell and value is OK")
  }
  
  // update "Data sheet"
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data")
  var effectiveDate = new Date()
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(effectiveDate,"GMT+5:30", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  if (editedValue == value2Watch1){
    // if "Awaiting documents, update start"
    dataSheet.getRange("P3").setValue(formattedDate)

  }
  else{
    // else update "end" date
  dataSheet.getRange("Q3").setValue(formattedDate)
  }
}


SAMPLE - Dropdown


SAMPLE - Output


SAMPLE - Data validation

